# POST (http service) angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have this POST data in my angular 2 application:

```
postServices(property) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(property);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers });
    return this._http.post(this._url, body, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And in my template i have this button:

```
 <button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled" 
 [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 'true' ? 'green' :'orange'"
         class="btn btn-warning">
         {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | toOnOff }}
 </button>
```

And how i can add event on `(click)=""` in my template with this http service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a click handler on button through which you can call `postService`.

```
<button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled" (click)= "callingPostService()"
 [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 'true' ? 'green' :'orange'"
         class="btn btn-warning">
         {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | toOnOff }}
 </button>
```

in your component, something like this would do

```
callingPostService() {
    this._myService.postService('prop');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what problem you try to solve but I guess

```
(click)="myService.postService('someProp')"
```

is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the click event on your button with a call that executes the service method:

```
<button (click)= "executePostService()">(...)</button>
```

The `executePostService` method will call the service as described below. You need not forget to subscribe on the observable (observables are lazy) otherwise the HTTP request won't be executed:

```
constructor(private service:SomeHttpService) {
}

callingPostService() {
  this.service.postService('prop').subscribe();
}
```