# How to get data and subscribe to it in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to get results and assingn it with observables but i am unable to get it can some one please help me.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { IStudent1 } from '../interface';
 import { IStudent2 } from '../interface';
 import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
 import {GetSocietyList} from './service'
  import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';

  @Component({
      selector: 'Search',
      templateUrl:  './components/search/search.html',
      directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES,    REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
       providers : [GetSocietyList],
       inputs : ['form']
    })

    export class Search {
    property:any = 'Add';
     data: string;
     form: FormGroup;
    prop: string = 'connenct';
    details: IStudent1[];
     details1: IStudent2[];

       constructor(fbld: FormBuilder,public http: Http,private _profileservice:GetSocietyList) {
      this.details = [];
      this.http = http;
       this._profileservice.getSocietyList()
        .subscribe(details => this.details = details);

        console.log(this.details);
   this.form = fbld.group({
        name: [''],
        age: ['', Validators.required],
        class: ['', Validators.required],
        grade: ['', Validators.required]

    });

}


   edit(id): any {
//console.log(id);
this.property = 'update';
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
this.http.get('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/editprofiledb/' + id, { headers: headers }).map(res=> res.json());}


}
```

I am trying to get results and assingn it with observables but i am unable to get it can some one please help me.

Comment: use `this.id` instead of `id` in `http.get` method

Answer (score 1):

you can use any functional operator like `map`to get the response.

```
edit(id): any {
    //console.log(id);
    this.property = 'update';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.get('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/editprofiledb/' + id, { headers: headers }).map(res=> res.json());
```

`

and in your component/directive you can then `subscribe` for it .

```
constructor(private service:SomeHttpService) {
}

callingGetService() {
  this.service.edit('id').subscribe();
}
```

have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824433/post-http-service-angular-2/38824668#38824668)

Comment: But here i am doing in one component

Comment: Try using `this.id` instead of `id ` in `this.http.get ` method

Comment: showing type error at   res.json());}  res not found

Comment: my guess is there's a problem while appending `id` to the url. try maybe + 'id' ? u need not remove `subscribe` method. it will consume your `observable`. so `http.get().map().subscribe()` would be right way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121409/discussion-between-candidj-and-nlr-p).